Class and macro with same name from different libraries
In my project I am using 2 libraries. One defines a Status macro and the other has a class named Status in a namespace. This results in a conflict when using the class Status in my code:
// first library
namespace Test {
    class Status {};
}

// second library
#define Status int

// my code
int main() {
    Test::Status test;
    return 0;
}

Error:
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
    8 | #define Status int

How can I use both libraries in my project?

Why do you have something like this #define Status int, when you can use using Status = int;? Maybe contact the library author and ask them to make changes?

Best approach would be to ditch the second library; it seems to follow terrible practice, even for C. But if you can't, then encapsulate it in another TU; wrap and export the essential functionality(either trough C++20 modules or classic public headers). Don't directly use the second library anywhere in your projects.

If you do not need to use the Status macro defined by the 2nd library, then you can simply do the following :
#include <second-library.h>
#undef Status
#include <first-library.h>

If you want to be able to use the Status macro defined by the 2nd library, and the macro expands to a type, you can do the following:
#include <second-library.h>
using Status2 = Status;
#undef Status
#include <first-library.h>

And then use it as Status2 instead of Status.
If you want to be able to use the Status macro, but the macro expands to something other than a type, then I am afraid there is no easy solution:

You could look at the definition of the macro and rewrite it with a different name, although this might get you into trouble if, in a future version of the library, they change the definition.

You might wrap the library with the macro into a library of your own, so that you can define everything you want with names that you choose, though this might be more work than you bargained for.



Create an alias instead of another macro, then undefine it.

I don't think there's a good way to overcome it in general . If the macro expands to a type like in OP's example, then you can use using Status2 = Status; followed by #undef Status.

The using needs to look like in my comment.

@MikeNakis, you missed the equal sign in the alias declaration

Compilation of your code
namespace Status {
    class Test();
}


Create a library named "Status"
Inside the "Status" create Test class

#define Status int

Replace every occurrence of the word Status to int

Test::Status test;

Inside the main function create a test object

there's a conflict here as you changed the Status[word] to int which converts the following statement Test::Status test; to this Test::int test;
so to solve this problem you have many choices

to undefine your Status word by the following command
#undef Status


to use another keyword for macro int by the following command
#define integer int


to create a header file 'filename.h' and put into it the following code
namespace Test { class Status(); } and #include <filename.h> in your file which extension is .cpp and be sure that you created the filename.h in your working directory.

